# Audio Recording | Pausing and Resuming

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript, recording

I'm currently working on a project that allows the user to record an audio message, however a request was recently made to allow them to pause the recording process and then continue recording (appending the new audio to follow the previous recording).

**Example:**

1. User presses record and makes their initial recording.
2. User presses a pause button to gather their thoughts, or what have you.
3. User clicks the record button again and continues the recording from where the previous had left off.
4. (Repeat until recording process is complete and upload is clicked.)

I am currently using **[recorder.js](https://github.com/jwagener/recorder.js/)** and have been extremely happy with it so far, however I feel that it lacks the features that I am looking for and I am not familiar enough with Flash / Actionscript to go digging into it and tinkering.

I was curious if any users had any suggestions for a full-featured solution or suggestions as how to implement something similar. A fairly cross-browser / cross-platform solution would be preferred but is not a hard requirement (primarily concerned with Chrome and IE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer a following code.

```
import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
import flash.media.Microphone;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.events.Event;

var microphone:Microphone;
var isPause:Boolean = false;
var soundRecording:ByteArray;

record_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onRecordStart);
recordPause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPauseResumeToggle);
recordStop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onRecordStop);
audioPlay_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlay);

function onRecordStart(e:MouseEvent=null):void 
{
    soundRecording = new ByteArray();
    microphone=Microphone.getMicrophone();
    microphone.rate=44;
}

function onPauseResumeToggle(e:MouseEvent=null):void
{
    if(!isPause)
    {
        microphone.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, gotMicData);
    }
    else
    {
        microphone.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, gotMicData);
    }

    isPause != isPause;
}

function onRecordStop(e:MouseEvent=null):void 
{
    isPause = false;
    microphone.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, gotMicData);
    soundRecording.position=0;
}

function gotMicData(micData:SampleDataEvent):void 
{
    soundRecording.writeBytes(micData.data);
}

function onPlay(e:MouseEvent=null):void 
{
    soundRecording.position=0;

    soundOutput = new Sound();
    soundOutput.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playSound);

    soundOutput.play();
}

function playSound(soundOutput:SampleDataEvent):void 
{
    if (! soundRecording.bytesAvailable>0) 
    {
        return;
    }
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++) 
    {
        var sample:Number=0;
        if (soundRecording.bytesAvailable>0) 
        {
            sample=soundRecording.readFloat();
        }
        soundOutput.data.writeFloat(sample);
        soundOutput.data.writeFloat(sample);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It has the following features:

- pause recording
- pause playback
- record time callback
- upload the recorded audio
- only upload button is inside flash

https://github.com/ehsan6sha/FlashWavRecorder